# Pass URL variable from parent page to tagret (classic ASP) page through iframe

Tags: javascript, html, url, iframe, asp-classic

I have developed an engine that I need to customize in order to be used on several websites.  I decided to display it through an iframe and I want to pass a simple parameter through the url to distinguish between different client sites.
I want to assign the variable in each site from the parent page like so:

```
<iframe src="...engine.com/targetpage.asp?id=1">
```

and say for another client site

```
<iframe src="..engine.com/targetpage.asp?id=2">
```

How do I process that in the target page? I tried a few JS & JQuery scripts but Im not to proficient with them so I either get null values or a "Method Not Allowed" error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the value from URL Parameter?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/979975/how-to-get-the-value-from-url-parameter), assuming that you aren't asking for `Request.QueryString("id")` and, actually, all the reference to ASP is not relevant.

Comment: If you just want targetpage.asp to capture and use the value of "id" then use Request.Querystring in ASP code as Alvaro suggests.  Is targetpage.asp on your own site with your client accessing it through an iframe on theirs?  If so then you should be able to use Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_REFERER") to capture the URL of the client's page